# Why didn't the code printed the line after "finally"? (Java)

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

I have a method with a try and catch block, and the code after the finally statement did not print ("end of a" line).

**The method threw an exception** and I suspect this is the reason. 
Is the reason for the line

```
System.out.println("end of a");
```

not printing because of the exception?

Here's the code:

> Test Class:

```
    public class Test
{
    Integer num;
    public Test(){
        this(0) ;
        System.out.println("Test constructor1 ");
    }
    public Test(int i){
        if (i>0) num = new Integer(i) ;
        System.out.println("Test constructor2 ");
    }
    public void a() throws Exception{
        try{
            if (num.intValue() > 0)
                System.out.println("num = "+num.intValue());
            System.out.println("executing a ");
            throw new Exception();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("exception caught in a");
            if (e instanceof NullPointerException) throw e;
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("finally in a");
        }
        System.out.println("end of a");
    }
}
```

> Main Class:

```
public class MainTest2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            Test t2 = new Test();
            t2.a();
            System.out.println("executing main1 ");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("exception caught in main");
        }
        System.out.println("ending main ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the reason for the line `System.out.println("end of a");` not printing because of the exception? **Exactly**

Comment: @OlafKock Ok, thanks. So I can understand that if an exception is thrown in a method, **only** the finally block will be printed and not anything else?

Comment: if *you* don't `catch` an exception, nothing else does. `finally` just briefly interrupts the thrown exception before it's thrown further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step by Step:**

1. when you are calling `a()` in `t2` the value of `num` in `t2` is `null` or not set in other words
2. if you run the `if (num.intValue() > 0)` it creates a `NullPointerException` (reason see step 1)
3. so the occured exeption triggers the `try` and it jumps into the `catch` block and gives a `NPE` via the `e` over to the `catch` block
4. the `catch` block tests for a `NPE` in `e`, this is true and so the `throw e` passes the exeption to the next instance
5. the `finally` block in `a()` is beeing executed
6. the programm leaves the try-catch-finally block, while having an unhandeled exeption open from Step 4
7. Step 6 triggers the requirement for the `throws Exception` in the declaration of `a()` and therefor `a()` stops executing and returns the exeption to `main()`
8. now `main()` is responsible for the exeption and running

**Conclusion:**
The line `System.out.println("end of a");` is never reached by the programm because it ran into a unhandeled exeption earlier, throw the exeption and stoped executing `a()` befor the line.

(Sorry for spelling or grammer errors :))

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the exception is `NullPointerException` caused due to `num.intValue()`. 
So when the exception arises `System.out.println("finally in a");` gets executed.
After this, since `e` is actually an instance of `NPE` the code returns directly on executing his piece code `if (e instanceof NullPointerException) throw e;`
And rhe last `sysout` is never executed.